# CSV File to MySQL Database

Tags: csv, mysql

I have a CSV file in the following format:

`"id","code","date","address","complete_url"`

Example data from the CSV:

```
"144003286","ICXT","20100104","NJ","http://www.orhancanceylan.com"
"144003286","SEED","20100104","NY","http://www.erbileren.com"
"144003286","ANX","20100104","CA","http://www.foursquareme.com"
"144003286","AIG","20100104","NJ","http://www.orhancanceylan.com"
```

I want to load all of the data into MySQL. I tried the following command:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\pb\\Documents/data.csv' 
INTO TABLE new_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '","' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

And I received the following error:

```
1265 Data truncated for column 'id' at row 1
 1261 Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns
 1261 Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns
 1261 Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns
 1261 Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns
 Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 5    3.620 sec
```

What is wrong with my code or CSV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changed `FIELDS TERMINATED BY` from `'","'` to `','`

Comment: Thank you very much ! I have a question about the output. It says 1265 Data truncated for column 'code' at row 1
 1265 Data truncated for column 'complete_url' at row 2
 1265 Data truncated for column 'complete_url' at row 3
 1265 Data truncated for column 'complete_url' at row 4
 1265 Data truncated for column 'complete_url' at row 5

What does it mean ?

Comment: The max-length of the field in your database is too short, so not all the data could be inserted (hence, some was truncated)

Comment: How shold I inspect the records that are not fitting my schema, because I have thousands of data I couldn't see them by looking